# Save and Save As option in Tableau Server 9

Tags: permissions, save, tableau-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow users to save their view on the Tableau server. I have set allow access permissions for 'download and save option' to the group while publishing the report to a particular group of users.

Even though when they log in the only option available for them is 'Revert' and 'Done'.

I have tried given ALL permissions to the user with no luck what so ever...
What can the issue be then?
I, as the owner, can see the "Save" "Save As" buttons,

Any help is appreciated. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#web_author_who.htm

Specifically:

> Download/Save As—determines whether the user sees the Save and Save As commands while they are editing a view, and whether they can save their changes to a new workbook. It also determines whether users can open a workbook on the server using Tableau Desktop.
>   To save changes to a workbook or save a workbook as a new workbook on Tableau Server, a user must have a site role of Publisher. The Save and Download/Save As capabilities must be set to Allow in the workbook permissions.

Also

> Note: Users with a site role of Interactor are not allowed to save or download workbooks.